# how to retrieve data from isolated storage?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to retrieve data from isolated storage in my window phone 7 application.Actually i stored my webservice responce xml file in to device data base.Now i wants to retrive data from device data base.
So how i can retrieve it?

My code is like this.
Iso

```
latedStorageSettings setting = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
 if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("latitude"))
            {
                setting.Add("latitude", ClsGetDeviceMap.lstLatitude.ElementAt<string>(i).Trim());  
            }
            else if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("longitude"))
            {
                setting.Add("longitude", ClsGetDeviceMap.lstLongLatitude.ElementAt<string>(i).Trim());
            }
            setting.Save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save data

```
settings[latitude]=...
```

Retrieve data

```
var latitude = settings[latitude]
```